# Javascript addEventListener not working as expected

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom-events, addeventlistener

I am looking into some common Javascript programs. The following one adds 4 buttons to the DOM and adds an event listener to each of them:

```
for(var i =0;i<5;i++){
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Button' + i));

    //function 1
    (function(i){
     btn.addEventListener('click', function(){console.log(i)});
     })(i);

    //function 2 commented
    /*btn.addEventListener('click', (function(i){
     return function(){
     console.log(i);
     }
     })(i));*/
    
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

both function 1 and function 2 add event listener to the buttons and work perfectly. I want to know, why the following code does not :-

```
for(var i =0;i<5;i++){
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Button' + i));

    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log('Clicked' + i);
    });
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

This code just logs 5 for every button on click. Why is that, I do not understand why it simply does not hold the value for i for each loop?

Comment: in both your example you create a closure immediately executed, so the local value of i is congruent with the expected result, in the third example you wait until the loop is finished then when you click the value of i its ever the maximum value of the iteration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `addEventListener` is added to an `eventTarget` while it is processing the `for`loop, it does not trigger the listener.

It is triggered later stage, and at that point the `for-loop` has finished it's execution and updated the value of `i`.

When you are creating a function inside the `for-loop` it is creating a closure and binding the value of `i`

Comment: ok..now I understand, but to get a little deeper, why isn't the event listen triggered, why does it wait for the for loop to finish. I can understand when a external call is made to an api to fetch data, the for loop does not wait for the response..but why in case of a event listener

Comment: _triggering_ is different from _adding_. Inside loop you are adding the event to the target. But triggering happens when you click on it

Answer (score 2):

Javascript has no block scope if you use `var`. So, using exactly your code, you can have the "expected result" replacing `var` for `let`:

```js
for(let i =0;i<5;i++){
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Button' + i));

    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log('Clicked' + i);
    });
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```